# Jsoup mobile data consumption

Tags: html-parsing, jsoup, network-utilization

I'm using Jsoup to parse in background the html of 3 different webpages every 10 minutes or so. However I found that in 2 days I consumed 18 mb of network data... Is there some way to reduce this huge data consumption? I don't need all the html page, is there a way to download only a part of the website html?

Comment: It depends on the site's structure. Which sites are you parsing? what are the parts that you need?

Comment: But from what I understand there is no way to download just a part of the html, you have to download all the document and then select the part that you need... Anyway I found that there is a maxBodySize attribute that I can set, it may help I think

Answer (score 0):

One way out would be to create a webservice that does the scraping and parsing and offers the results back to you in a condensed form. maybe create something on openshift?

18MB is actually not much over 2 days. Are you sure you can't afford this?